# How to gzip all .BRIK in all Sub-Directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gzip

I have a lot of files with .BRIK extension that take up a lot of space and need to be gzip. However, the files are scattered in multiple folders and few-level deep. I cannot find an answer to gzip *BRIK without doing one folder at a time.

Any suggestion?

So far, what I have been doing is just gzip *BRIK on each folder

Comment: find /blah_directory -iname \*.BRIK -exec gzip {} \;

Comment: You can do several folders in parallel, but I am not sure if that helps. In other words, it is not clear to me what suggestions you want.

Comment: How compressible are the BRIK'd files - its possible you will not gain much?

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
find . -name '*.BRIK' -type f -exec gzip --best -v {} +
```

This would find all regular files that have the filename suffix `.BRIK` in or under the current directory.  For batches of these files, the `gzip` command would be called with the options `--best` and `-v` to compress the files.